# C++ Program Functions

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble with my functions. When I use a function to manipulate an array, and print it and move on to the next manipulation function, it uses the array that was previously manipulated instead of the original array. For example, when my function converts every negative number to a positive, I call the next function which zeros out all even numbers, and my array prints out all zeros, instead of using the array from the original.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define NUMS_PER_LINE 10    // maximum numbers to be printed on each line.

int numbers[100];   // array to hold upto 100 integer numbers.
int numcnt;     // actual count (<=100) of numbers in above array.

// reads file content into array

void read_array_from_file (const char filename[])
{
    ifstream inpfile(filename);

    if (!inpfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Can't open file : " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    numcnt=0;   // Initialise count of read numbers

    // Read numbers from the file into array.
    inpfile >> numbers[numcnt];

    while (!inpfile.eof())      // Read until EOF is reached.
    {
        numcnt++;   // Got one more number from input file.
        inpfile >> numbers[numcnt];
    }

    inpfile.close();

    return;
}

// Print out all the values in the array

void print_array_content (int numsinaline)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<numcnt+1; i++)
    {
        if ((i % numsinaline) == 0)
            cout << endl;
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    return;
}

// calculate average

double calculate_average ()
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;

    for (i=0; i<(numcnt-1); i++)
    {
       sum += numbers[i];
    }

    return (sum/(numcnt-1));
}

// Find numbers larger and smaller than the average.

void find_numbers_smaller_and_larger_than_average (int &larger, int &smaller, int  average)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<(numcnt-1); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < average)
            smaller++;
        else if (numbers[i] > average)
            larger++;
    }

    return;
}

// Convert negative numbers to positive in the array 'numbers'.

void convert_negative_to_positive ()
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<(numcnt-1); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < 0)
            numbers[i] *= -1;
    }

    return;
}



// Convert all even numbers into zero.
void zero ()
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<numcnt; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > 0)
            numbers[i] *= 0;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "instead of using the array from the original"?

Comment: you shouldn't have `return;` when the method is suppose to return void.

Comment: @progenhard: That's not really the problem here (and other than that it's perfectly valid).

Comment: looks like you are using ONE global array."numbers[i] *= -1;" modifies this original array. you need to make a copy first if you want to continue with the original one

Comment: for loops shoudl start at 0 to numcnt (for (i=0; i<=numcnt; i++)), some of your functions are not working properly

Comment: @progenhard a void function can be terminated by a `return` statement having no expression, i.e. returning nothing.

Comment: @Allexey Where is your main?

Comment: Hm... interesting thanks for the info had no idea.

Comment: @larrylampco I didnt include my main because I don't think it has anything to do with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using a global variable for your array, so you are never passing it to your function.  When you change a global variable in the function, it changes the data in the array.  You should be passing that data into the function and NOT using global variables.

Second, `while(!inpFile.eof())` is **bad**!  Don't do it.

For file streams:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::ifstream fin("myfile");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(fin), std::istream_iterator(),  std::back_inserter<vector<int> >(numbers));
```

Those 3 lines will read the entire file into the vector "numbers".

Third, when declaring your functions, pass the array:

```
void myFunction(const std::vector<int>& vec); // if you aren't going to change the vector
```

or
    void myFunction(std::vector& vec); // if you are going to change it

and you would call it by simply:

```
myFunction(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

*" it uses the array that was previously manipulated instead of the original array."*

Obviously because you have your array declared globally

`int numbers[100];`

Outside all functions.

When you perform one operation on this array, the element get modified and the new values will be used for next functions.

Instead of this, save of copy of your original array and then use this copy whenever you wish to work on original array

Comment: when you say use a copy do you mean I declare the array outside the functions and then copy the array into each function

Comment: @Allexey nah not like that. I meant, like you can have another array say `int backup_numbers[100];`, after initially filling `numbers` copy its content into `backup_numbers` using `memcpy` or just a simple for loop, and then whenever you need to work on original array, restore back `numbers` from `backup_numbers` using a for loop or `memcpy`

Answer (score 0):

All your operations act on a single global variable, `numbers`. If you modify it in any of your functions its values will also change in every other occurrence.

Instead, provide a way to tell your functions *which* array you want to use, how many elements it contains and use several arrays. This also enables you to get rid of the global variable.

#### Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int array_size_t;

void print_array(int array[], array_size_t size){
  for(array_size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  int a1[] = {1,2,3,4};
  int a2[] = {1,3,3,7,0,0,0,0};
  print_array(a1,4);
  print_array(a2,8);  
}
```

#### Remark

If you're allowed use standard containers such as `std::vector` instead. The solution above is more C than C++-like.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly manipulating your array inside of your functions since it is defined globally, instead of passing in a copy as a parameter.

```
void modify(int[] array) {

    //Modify copied array here

}

int main() {
    int numbers[100];
    int copyNumbers[100];
    //Copy numbers
    memcpy(copyNumbers, numbers, sizeof(numbers));

    modify(copyNumbers);
    //Use modified array
    memcpy(copyNumbers, numbers, sizeof(numbers)); //Set back to original
    modify(copyNumbers);  //Modify copy again as original
}
```

Comment: Your copyNumbers = numbers is an invalid assignment which will cause a compiling error.

Comment: You are correct, thanks. Been a while since I used C++. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using global variable. All your operation on numbers whatever index will change your certain position's value.

Another potential risk is if your input file contains more than 100 integers, you will do

```
inpfile >> numbers[100];
```

or some index number greater than 100.
which will cause a segmentation fault.

You should be very careful when using global variables

Comment: thank you, i did not understand the difference between global arrays until now!